Definite article required before proper possessive plural noun?
My wife claims it's incorrect to say "we'll be over at Smiths' house." I think this may be a regional thing, but she claims the article is required: "we'll be over at the Smiths' house."
I'm from SE Michigan and we'd often shorten it even more, dropping the "house" or "place", just saying "we'll be over at Smiths'"
I can't find a rule saying the definite article is required in front of a plural possessive proper noun. I found one saying it's allowed, which I agree with, but not that it's required.
Is this construction regional, or wrong in NA English?

I am a life-long Marylander and have never heard (or even heard of) your usage without the definite article.

It seems a bit odd even if not possessive. There's plenty of guidance about making plurals out of last names, but they typically operate as proper nouns ("the Johnsons" means specifically "those Johnsons next door"). Leaving out the definite article feels useful only in a family reunion, "Calling all Johnsons!" After all, do you enjoy listening "to Beatles" or have "all Ramones' albums"?

(Mind you, using the last name to refer to one person is different. "I'll be over at Smith's, and Wesson will be there too.")

Your wife is right. Over at Smith's, sounds like Smith is a first name. The Smiths are the nicest people. Obviously, you can't leave it off there.

Several of those examples aren't possessive though, which normally changes the requirement for an article. Your last example is what I'm talking about: "I'll be over at (the) Smiths' (house), and Wesson will be there too." Smith isn't referring to one person, it's plural and possessive, which is where we sometimes wouldn't use the "the".

The other examples though, aren't possessive, so they aren't good examples: "The Johnsons" "the Beatles". I guess you made Ramones possessive, but in that case I'd argue that the proper name of the band is "The Ramones" and it only sounds weird because you omitted part of their name, because the article is part of the proper name of the band.

Again, "The Smiths are the nicest people" isn't an example of what I'm asking, because it's not possessive.

"... aren't possessive though, which normally changes the requirement for an article" —It does? Doesn't seem so to me. "The Guggenheim's new acquisition," "the Pentagon's press release," "the Eiffel Tower's radio antenna." I was intentionally eliminating possessive from the equation, as all those sibilants ("Smithses's, precious") get confusing, and because it doesn't hinge on it. "... I'd argue that the proper name of the band is 'The Ramones' and it only sounds weird because you omitted part of their name..." That's kind of the argument for "The Smiths" and "The Johnsons" as well.

Smith's or Smiths' sounds like a shop. I doubt anybody has bothered to make a definite rule about this, so saying it's "wrong" is extreme, but if you're talking about a couple/family it's definitely usual to say "the Smiths' house", because the family is "the Smiths".

It's all a bit academic, because speech is the final arbiter of language, and it's impossible to differentiate the Taylors house (plural noun adjunct) from The Taylor's house (singular possessive) OR from The Taylors' house (plural possessive, where we neither write nor articulate possessive /s/ after a noun pluralised by /s/). They're all perfectly valid, though. As is singular noun adjunct the Taylor house, but idiomatically that's a bit unlikely unless that house is very well known, as with the singular noun adjunct the Greenwich meridian.

"X's house" can be used when X refers to a single person (usually a first name or full name, but some people refer to friends/coworkers by just their last name). But it's always "The X's" when referring to a family.

@AndyBonner in your first comment, that band's name was The Beatles. Although "Do you listen to Beatles music" seems good.

@WeatherVane Yes, using that as an illustration of "a plural identifying a specific group of people, where 'the' is non-optional." Without it it sounds like they're just some of many Beatles. Granted, I'm not sure "The" is as officially attached to the Ramones, though any casual overview of writing about them shows it's used. (And I'm pointedly ignoring attractive red herrings like "Oh yeah, I'm known to get down to some Beatles from time to time," extending the name to refer to a noncount amount of musical product...)

@AndyBonner yes, it's less clear with the Ramones, and I looked at images of their drum kit, which unlike The Beatles does not say The Ramones, but Marky Ramone (a former member). Others were called Joey Ramone, Johnny Ramone, Dee Dee Ramone, and Tommy Ramone. So they were the Ramones :)

@Lambie - "Over at Smith's, sounds like Smith is a first name." Or a man being referred to by his surname alone, as used to be common.


My wife claims it's incorrect to say "we'll be over at Smiths' house."

If she, or you, refers to the person who lives there as "Smith" (i.e. the surname only and this is not uncommon) then "Smith's house" is fine. (In essence, it is no different from "... over at John's house.")
If she, or you, does not, then the Smiths' house would be correct = the house of that family of whom you are aware and who are called Smith - and that is fine. The Smiths' specifies the particular Smith family from all others of the same name.
The latter is far more common.
The answer thus depends on the context - as it usually does.

It's all a bit academic, because speech is the final arbiter of language, and it's impossible to differentiate...

1: the Taylors house (plural noun adjunct)
from
2: The Taylor's house (singular possessive)
OR from...
3: The Taylors' house (plural possessive, where we neither write nor articulate possessive /s/ after a noun pluralised by /s/).

They're all perfectly valid, though. As is singular noun adjunct the Taylor house, but idiomatically that's a bit unlikely unless the house is very well known, as with the singular noun adjunct the Greenwich meridian.

As I said above in a comment, I don't think think your singular possessive case is common.

In fact, I think we don't say it precisely because we wouldn't be able to distinguish the singular possessive and plural possessive in speech. So the direct article is how we tell what's meant.

Nor do we use the plural noun adjunct.

This seems kind of like an answer to a different question. The OP was asking about deleting the article, and it's present in all your examples. (Also, while I often make the point "You can say [bla bla bla] and it's perfectly valid, just not idiomatically common," with this OP it seems the emphasis is on idiomaticity, and it might be wise to avoid accidentally giving the impression that unheard-of patterns are "valid.")
